# In Numbers, how can I determine the default formatting of cells in rows that have just been added to a sheet?

Tags: numbers, formatting

When using Numbers, I have noticed that whenever I add a new row *above* existing rows, all of the formatting for the new row is exactly like the rows below it. However, if I add a new row *below* existing rows, the formatting is reverted to the default formatting for a brand new sheet. There are other inconsistencies around the choices that Numbers makes when determining the formatting of new cells and rows, but this is the one that I find to be more consistent.

Is there a way to set up a default formatting (font name and size) for all new cells and rows? Something like the default templates in Microsoft Office. Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following [tutorial](http://www.apple.com/findouthow/iwork/#numbers-table) at Apple that has the answer to my own question: The default table styles are always taken from the table style list that you choose from the panel on the bottom-left corner of the screen.

The solution to my problem is to use the **Create New Table Style** command under the **Format** menu and adding a brand new table style. As long as this new style remains selected, it is the one that the table will keep as a whole.

I have tried this at home and it works as advertised.